# Spot the data difference between 2 worksheets on each row with multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

Would like to ask help on how to spot the data difference between 2 worksheets on each row with multiple columns.

For example, I have 2 worksheets and I need to check if Worksheet1 Row A exists in Worksheet 2 (needs to check each row in Worksheet 2)

The current script that I'm using only checks row by row and will not be accurate if the arrangement of rows doesn't match.

Here's the script:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rngCell As Range
     
    For Each rngCell In Worksheets("RP").UsedRange
        If Not rngCell = Worksheets("R4").Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column) Then
            rngCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: *"Row A exists in Worksheet 2"* rows are numbered,  do you mean column A ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you an approach to this type of question, using a screenshot. In my Excel workbook, I have two sheets. The first one contains the first 5 values and the second one the first 4 odd values (1, 3, 5, 7).

I've created different columns, checking if both values are equal (green result) and checking if the value exists somewhere (orange result).

The colours are configured, using conditional formatting, whose definition is shown in the screenshot.

For your information: the columns "C" up to "F" are not needed for configuring the conditional formatting, I've just shown them in order to learn about how to work with conditional formatting, based on formulae (first write the formula and check the results, and afterwards use the formula in a conditional formatting definition).

[image]